# "Python: TypeError - 'str' object is not callable when using format() method"

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the `format()` method in Python for string formatting, but I keep getting a `TypeError` that says "'str' object is not callable." I've checked my code, and I can't figure out what's causing this error. Can someone help me understand what might be going wrong?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```py
# Some code that defines a string
my_string = "Hello, {}!"

# Now, I want to format the string with a name
name = "John"
formatted_string = my_string.format(name)

# The next line is where I'm encountering the TypeError
print(formatted_string())
```

I expected this to print `"Hello, John!"` but instead, I'm getting a `TypeError`. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `formatted_string` is a string. You can't call (append parentheses) it.

Answer (score 0):

```py
formatted_string = my_string.format(name)  # this is a str

formatted_string()  # adding () means trying to call `formatted_string` as a function
```

and `str` objects cannot be called, hence the error message: `"'str' object is not callable."`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parenthesis after the formatted_string in your print statement.

```
my_string = "Hello, {}!"
name = "John"
formatted_string = my_string.format(name)
print(formatted_string)
```

Output: `Hello, John!`